# How to override or remove the master page css in webpage

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

In my application ,I have a master page where i have included more than 10 .js files and some .css files .
In sample.aspx page I have another set of .js file and .css file.

I getting a big problem in this form means css completly collapsed,so I have to exclude those file which i have on master page and i Can't remove those file from master page because my others forms are using those file ,Is there any solution to exclude those script tags in only sample.aspx page

Thanks

Comment: You can't "un-include" a css file. So one kludge that springs to mind is to make the page stand alone, that is, not use the master page. Copy and paste what you need from the master page into sample.aspx.

Comment: That sounds pretty much like a back-end question.

Comment: Maybe the better way around is to fix the problems that breaks your form? Cannot believe it would be a big problem once you find the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If your sample.aspx inherits your master Page you don't need to link your .js/.css files in the sample.aspx. But if you want to use your .jss/.css files only on your sample.aspx, it won't cause you any error, just separate your .js/.css files on a folder in your solution

Comment: I have to add another set of files on sample.aspx page

Comment: what do you mean add another file? you mean you wanna add .js/.css files? if that's the case still use it in your master page if your sample.aspx page inherits your master